# Python multidimensional list initialization ...Or pure python equivalent of numpy.zero

Tags: python

I need to create a 2x2x2x2 dimensional list in "pure" python, i,e, not using numpy.

Using numpy, I would simply write:

```
numpy.zeros((2,2,2,2))
```

In "plain python" I tried:

```
>>> aa=[[[[0]*2]*2]*2]
>>> aa
[[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]]
```

looks good, however

```
>>> aa[0][0][0][0]=1
```

results in:

```
>>> aa
[[[[1, 0], [1, 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 0]]]]
```

which is not what I want, of course

I always felt that this mutable object stuff in python was a strange design choice... anyway, is there a simple pythonic way to achieve what I want hopefully a one liner not requiring import(s).
I understand that deep copying the list would fix the problem, but it is far from feeling elegant... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> aa = [[[0 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]

>>> aa
[[[0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]

>>> aa[0][0][0] = 1
>>> aa
[[[1, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Elegant?... not sure, but definitively answers the question! thx! :-)